# Conceptual question about bias of an estimator

Tags: self-study, bias

I cannot see the notion of 'bias' of an estimator in a statistical model clearly. Here is my concern:

Let $(Y,X)$ be a training data set. I generate this dataset according to the model $Y=g(X;\theta^g)+\epsilon$, with $\epsilon\sim~N(0,\sigma^2)$. The parameter $\theta^g,\sigma$ are all chosen by me. So I know the true value of these parameter. (I can even generate the dataset via a deterministic rule, i.e., pseudo random number generator)

Now I give this data to my friend who has no idea about the true model. He set up his own model: $Y=f(X;\theta^f)+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon\sim~N(0,\sigma^2)$. So in this case, his model is wrong. This happens a lot in pratice, i.e., we usually don't know the true underlying data generating process.

Now he want's to derive estimator for $\theta^f$. He came up with 3 different estimators: 1) $\hat{\theta}^f$ by MLE; 2) $\tilde{\theta}^f$ by least square, i.e., minimizing $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}[y_i-f(x_i;\theta^f)]^2$; $\bar{\theta}^f$ by minimizing a different objective function $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}[y_i-f(x_i;\theta^f)]^2+\lambda\sum\limits_{j=1}^{p}(\theta^f_j)^2$, where $\lambda$ is a shrinkage parameter.

Then my friend use cross validation to determine the value for $\lambda$, and finally, he finds that by setting $\lambda=0.5$, and obtaining $\bar{\theta}^f$. Then plug this $\bar{\theta}^f$ into the model $f(X;\theta^f)$, this works better than plugging in $\hat{\theta}^f$ and $\tilde{\theta}^f$. So my friend decides to use the estimator $\bar{\theta}^f$.

My question is: how to compute the bias of $\bar{\theta}^f$. The bias of $\bar{\theta}^f$ is defined as $\mathbb{E}[\bar{\theta}^f]-\theta^f$. Suppose our sample size $n$ is large, then we could use bootstrap to get the distribution of $\bar{\theta}^f$ and compute the mean of this distribution, denoted by $\mu_{\bar{\theta}^f}$, then we replace $\mathbb{E}[\bar{\theta}^f]$ by $\mu_{\bar{\theta}^f}$ and replace $\theta^f$ by $\bar{\theta}^f$ , i.e., we use $\mu_{\bar{\theta}^f}-\bar{\theta}^f$ as an estimator for $\mathbb{E}[\bar{\theta}^f]-\theta^f$. I don't know based on what theory we can claim $\bar{\theta}^f$ is close to $\theta^f$ and can we quantify how close are they? $\bar{\theta}^f$ is not even a consistent estimator of $\theta^f$, i.e., you can't say that as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $\bar{\theta}^f\rightarrow\theta^f$. Another question is: is this bias meaningful? since in this example, we all know that my friend's model is wrong.

Comment: whenever you discuss this kind of issues, you need to make some assumptions. One assumption your friend **has** to make is that the data actually came from his model. We all know this is almost never the case, but in order to discuss statistics we have to make such an assumption.

Comment: @YairDaon I agree, this is exactly what in my mind, then the question is my friend believe the data came from his model, then there must be a TRUE value of this model parameter $\theta^f$ right? But in my question, the estimator he used is $\bar{\theta}^f$, which is very unlikely to be a consistent estimator of the TRUE value $\theta^f$, then I don't see the logic of using $\mu_{\bar{\theta}^f}-\bar{\theta}^f$ as an approximation for the bias of $\bar{\theta}^f$, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[\bar{\theta}^f]-\theta^f$. But I believe most software compute bias this way

Comment: how could there be a true value if the model itself is wrong? If you want to consider a question of a parameter being correct or an estimator of it being consistent, you have to use data generated from the true model.

Comment: @YairDaon OK, then how to compute the bias of $\bar{\theta}^f$ in my problem, i.e., the model is wrong. If you use software, it still will report the bias, how does that bias come from, and is that bias meaningful? or how should we interpret the bias report from the software?

Comment: I tend to think that bias **is** meaningful. I have no clue what the program does, though. Great question, BTW. I would +5 it if I could.

Comment: @YairDaon Thanks. I asked my professor, he said the way software compute the bias of an estimator is what I suggested, but he couldn't answer my follow up question as I wrote here.